alternative way of exit and die in magento
i want to stop further executions of magento but without using exit, this is a PHP CS issue, how can i? i used return but execution did not stop,
  public function aroundOnThreeDSRequired(
        \P3\PaymentGateway\Model\Method\P3Method $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $threeDSVersion, 
        $res) 
{
        setcookie('threeDSRef', $res['threeDSRef'], time()+315);
        
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('payment_gateway_cookies'); //gives table name with prefix

        $order_num= $this->request->getParam('trRef');
        $sql = "Insert Into " . $tableName . " ( value,order_number) Values ('".$res['threeDSRef']."','". $order_num."' )";
        $connection->query($sql);
       
        // check for version
       $html =  Gateway::silentPost($res['threeDSURL'], $res['threeDSRequest']);

        if ($threeDSVersion >= 200) {
            // Silently POST the 3DS request to the ACS in the IFRAME
            // Remember the threeDSRef as need it when the ACS responds
            $_SESSION['threeDSRef'] = $res['threeDSRef'];
        }
         $this->response
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html', true)
            ->setBody($html)
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }


use the return statement
